# amqplib: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

## What I am trying to do

I try to create rabbit-mq publisher & subscriber. It works as expected until I try to restart my rabbit-mq server.

## What works

I use `rabbitmq:3-management` docker image, `ampqlib 5.3`, and Node.js `11.10.0` to make this simple program:

```
const q = 'tasks';

const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const amqplib = require("amqplib");

function createChannel() {
    return amqplib.connect("amqp://root:toor@0.0.0.0:5672/")
        .then((conn) => conn.createChannel());
}

Promise.all([createChannel(), createChannel()])

    .then(async (channels) => {
        const [publisherChannel, consumerChannel] = channels;

        // publisher
        await publisherChannel.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            return publisherChannel.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from("something to do"));
        });

        // consumer
        await consumerChannel.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            return consumerChannel.consume(q, function(msg) {
                if (msg !== null) {
                    console.log(msg.content.toString());
                    consumerChannel.ack(msg);
                }
            });
        });

    })

    .catch(console.warn);
```

So, first of all, I made two channels. One as publisher, and the other as consumer.

The publisher emit `something to do` message to `tasks` queue.

The consumer then catch the message and print it to the screen using `console.log`.

It works as expected.

## What doesn't work

### First Attempt

```
const q = 'tasks';

const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const amqplib = require("amqplib");

function createChannel() {
    return amqplib.connect("amqp://root:toor@0.0.0.0:5672/")
        .then((conn) => conn.createChannel());
}

Promise.all([createChannel(), createChannel()])

    .then((channels) => {

        // Let's say rabbitmq is down, and then up again
        execSync("docker stop rabbitmq");
        execSync("docker start rabbitmq");

        return channels;
    })

    .then(async (channels) => {
        const [publisherChannel, consumerChannel] = channels;

        // publisher
        await publisherChannel.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            return publisherChannel.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from("something to do"));
        });

        // consumer
        await consumerChannel.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            return consumerChannel.consume(q, function(msg) {
                if (msg !== null) {
                    console.log(msg.content.toString());
                    consumerChannel.ack(msg);
                }
            });
        });

    })

    .catch(console.warn);
```

Similar to my previous attempt, but this time I try to stop and start rabbit-mq container (restarting the server) before proceed.

It doesn't work, I get this error instead:

```
{ Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake
    at Socket.endWhileOpening (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:260:17)                                                           
    at Socket.emit (events.js:202:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
  cause:
   Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake
       at Socket.endWhileOpening (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:260:17)                                                        
       at Socket.emit (events.js:202:15)
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17),
  isOperational: true }
[guldan@draenor labs]$ node --version
v11.10.0
[guldan@draenor labs]$ docker start rabbitmq && node test.js
rabbitmq
{ Error: Channel ended, no reply will be forthcoming
    at rej (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:195:7)                                                                                  
    at Channel.C._rejectPending (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:197:28)                                                            
    at Channel.C.toClosed (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:165:8)                                                                   
    at Connection.C._closeChannels (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:394:18)                                                      
    at Connection.C.toClosed (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:401:8)                                                             
    at Object.accept (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:96:18)                                                                     
    at Connection.mainAccept [as accept] (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:64:33)                                                 
    at Socket.go (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:478:48)                                                                        
    at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:539:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
  cause:
   Error: Channel ended, no reply will be forthcoming
       at rej (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:195:7)                                                                               
       at Channel.C._rejectPending (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:197:28)                                                         
       at Channel.C.toClosed (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:165:8)                                                                
       at Connection.C._closeChannels (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:394:18)                                                   
       at Connection.C.toClosed (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:401:8)                                                          
       at Object.accept (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:96:18)                                                                  
       at Connection.mainAccept [as accept] (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:64:33)                                              
       at Socket.go (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:478:48)                                                                     
       at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
       at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:539:12)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17),
  isOperational: true }
```

### Second attempt

My first attempt didn't work. So, I try to create new channel after restarting the server:

```
const q = 'tasks';

const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const amqplib = require("amqplib");

function createChannel() {
    return amqplib.connect("amqp://root:toor@0.0.0.0:5672/")
        .then((conn) => conn.createChannel());
}

Promise.all([createChannel(), createChannel()])

    .then((channels) => {

        // Let's say rabbitmq is down, and then up again
        execSync("docker stop rabbitmq");
        execSync("docker start rabbitmq");

        return Promise.all([createChannel(), createChannel()]);
        // return channels;
    })

    .then(async (channels) => {
        const [publisherChannel, consumerChannel] = channels;

        // publisher
        await publisherChannel.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            return publisherChannel.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from("something to do"));
        });

        // consumer
        await consumerChannel.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            return consumerChannel.consume(q, function(msg) {
                if (msg !== null) {
                    console.log(msg.content.toString());
                    consumerChannel.ack(msg);
                }
            });
        });

    })

    .catch(console.warn);
```

And this time, I got this error instead:

```
{ Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake
    at Socket.endWhileOpening (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:260:17)                                                           
    at Socket.emit (events.js:202:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
  cause:
   Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake
       at Socket.endWhileOpening (/home/guldan/Projects/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:260:17)                                                        
       at Socket.emit (events.js:202:15)
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17),
  isOperational: true }
```

I'm not really sure, but I think the error is related to It might be related to https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/issues/101.

## What I want

I want workaround/solution to reconnect to rabbitmq after the server restarted. Any explanation/suggestion is also welcomed.

## Edit

I try to go deeper and modify my code a bit:

```
const q = 'tasks';

const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const amqplib = require("amqplib");

async function createConnection() {
    console.log("connect");
    const conn = amqplib.connect("amqp://root:toor@0.0.0.0:5672/");
    console.log("connected");
    return conn;
}

async function createChannel(conn) {
    console.log("create channel");
    const channel = conn.createChannel({durable: false});
    console.log("channel created");
    return channel;
}

async function createConnectionAndChannel() {
    const conn = await createConnection();
    const channel = await createChannel(conn);
    return channel;
}

Promise.all([createConnectionAndChannel(), createConnectionAndChannel()])

    .then((channels) => {

        // Let's say rabbitmq is down, and then up again
        console.log("restart server");
        execSync("docker stop rabbitmq");
        execSync("docker start rabbitmq");
        console.log("server restarted");

        return Promise.all([createConnectionAndChannel(), createConnectionAndChannel()]);
        // return channels;
    })

    .then(async (channels) => {
        console.log("channels created");
        const [publisherChannel, consumerChannel] = channels;

        // publisher
        console.log("publish");
        await publisherChannel.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            console.log("published");
            return publisherChannel.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from("something to do"));
        });

        // consumer
        console.log("consume");
        await consumerChannel.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            console.log("consumed");
            return consumerChannel.consume(q, function(msg) {
                if (msg !== null) {
                    console.log(msg.content.toString());
                    consumerChannel.ack(msg);
                }
            });
        });

    })

    .catch(console.warn);
```

And I get this output:

```
connect
connected
connect
connected
create channel
channel created
create channel
channel created
restart server
server restarted
connect
connected
connect
connected
{ Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake
    at Socket.endWhileOpening (/home/guldan/Projects/kata/merapi-plugin-service-rabbit/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:260:17)                                                                                             
    at Socket.emit (events.js:202:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
  cause:
   Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake
       at Socket.endWhileOpening (/home/guldan/Projects/kata/merapi-plugin-service-rabbit/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:260:17)                                                                                          
       at Socket.emit (events.js:202:15)
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17),
  isOperational: true }
```

So I guess amqplib is **able to re-connect** but **fail to create channel**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I manage to find the answer:

```
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const amqp = require("amqplib");

async function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

async function createChannel(config) {
    const { url, publishers, listeners } = Object.assign({url: "", publishers: {}, listeners: {}}, config);
    try {
        // create connection
        const connection = await amqp.connect(url);
        let channel = null;
        connection._channels = [];
        connection.on("error", (error) => {
            console.error("Connection error : ", config, error);
        });
        connection.on("close", async (error) => {
            if (channel) {
                channel.close();
            }
            console.error("Connection close : ", config, error);
            await sleep(1000);
            createChannel(config);
        });
        // create channel
        channel = await connection.createConfirmChannel();
        channel.on("error", (error) => {
            console.error("Channel error : ", config, error);
        });
        channel.on("close", (error) => {
            console.error("Channel close : ", config, error);
        });
        // register listeners
        for (queue in listeners) {
            const callback = listeners[queue];
            channel.assertQueue(queue, { durable: false });
            channel.consume(queue, callback);
        }
        // publish
        for (queue in publishers) {
            const message = publishers[queue];
            channel.assertQueue(queue, { durable: false });
            channel.sendToQueue(queue, message);
        }
        return channel;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Create connection error : ", error);
        await sleep(1000);
        createChannel(config);
    }
}

async function main() {
    // publish "hello" message to queue
    const channelPublish = await createChannel({
        url: "amqp://root:toor@0.0.0.0:5672",
        publishers: {
            "queue": Buffer.from("hello"),
        }
    });

    // restart rabbitmq
    execSync("docker stop rabbitmq");
    execSync("docker start rabbitmq");

    // consume message from queue
    const channelConsume = await createChannel({
        url: "amqp://root:toor@0.0.0.0:5672",
        listeners: {
            "queue": (message) => {
                console.log("Receive message ", message.content.toString());
            },
        }
    });

    return true;
}

main().catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Basically, I attach the channel into connection. So whenever the connection yield error (e.g: rabbitmq server turned off), the program will wait for a second, and try to create a new connection.

The drawback is, I will loose the reference to the old connection and it's channel.

In order to overcome this trouble, I have store the queue, publishers, and consumers information somewhere else (in this case I put it as `createChannel`'s parameter).

Finally, every time I reconnect, I will also make the channel as well as constructing every publisher and consumer.

Not quite convenient, but at least it work as intended.

Answer (score 10):

For any future users who might be having this issue:

Make sure the `port` is set to `5672` ( `local amqp server`) and not `15672` (`amqp web management console`).

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this issue because I was passing the URL "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:15672/" But Now I passed the URL "amqp://localhost" in the connection URL.After passing my issue got fixed.

Comment: you can also use sape path but with other port like this: amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672

Answer (score 0):

Losing reference doesn't seem to matter here, rabbitmq creates the channel only if it doesn't exist and if the channel exists the new variable refrerence will point to the same channel. So, not attemting to store the reference might make the application more lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to solve the problem:

There are a few stapes to solve this problem

1. Create a user from RabbitMQ management (Initially it comes with No access )
2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRitE.png)

here i have created a user called test. Initially the "can access virtual hosts " is made No access.

1. Click on the test.
2. Go to permissions
3. set permission and make virtual Host "/".
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB4v0.png)

No try to connect.